# What Join to use against 2 Tables for All Data

Tags: sql, join

Hi I am looking to find out what join I would use if I wanted to join 2 tables together. I currently have a list of all students so 25 students to 1 class and the other table only shows 7 of those names with their test results.

What I would like is to have 1:1 join for the ones with the test results and the other ones without I would like to show them underneath so all in all I have 20 records.

If somebody could please advise on how I could achieve this please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have 25 students and want 20 records?

Comment: Refer this:

http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/261/join#t=201701310703048805128

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want an OUTER JOIN.

For this example, we'll assume that there is a table named `student` and that it contains a column named `id` which is UNIQUE (or PRIMARY) KEY.

We'll also assume that there is another table named `test_result` which contains a column named `student_id`, and that column is a foreign key referencing the `id` column in `student`.

For demonstration purposes, we'll just make up some names for the other columns that might appear in these tables, `name` and `score`.

```
  SELECT s.id 
       , s.name 
       , r.score
    FROM student s
    LEFT
    JOIN test_result r
      ON r.student_id = s.id
   ORDER
      BY r.student_id IS NULL
       , s.score DESC
       , s.id
```

Note that if `student_id` is not unique in `test_result`, there is potential to return multiple rows that match a row in `student`.

To get (at most) one row returned from `test_result` per `student`, we could use an inline view.

```
  SELECT s.id 
       , s.name 
       , r.score
    FROM student s
    LEFT
    JOIN ( SELECT t.student_id
                , MAX(t.score) AS score
             FROM test_result t
            GROUP BY t.student_id
         ) r
      ON r.student_id = s.id
   ORDER
      BY r.student_id IS NULL
       , s.score DESC
       , s.id
```

The expressions in the ORDER BY clause are designed to return the students that have matching row(s) in `test_result` first, followed by students that don't.

This is just a demonstration, and very likely excludes some important criteria, such as which test a score should be returned for. But without a sample schema and some example data, we're just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `left outer join` or a `full outer join`.

The `left outer join` will show all students and their tests if they have them.

```
select *
from Students as s
  left outer join Tests as t
    on s.StudentId = t.StudentId
```

The `full outer join` will show all students with their tests if they have them, and tests even if they do not have students.

```
select *
from Students as s
  full outer join Tests as t
    on s.StudentId = t.StudentId
```

Comment: thanks guys, will have a go and let you know how I get on.